# Range of all variables in List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list in Prolog like this:

```
Puzzle = [ A1, A2, A3,
           B1, B2, B3,
           C1, C2, C3 ].
```

And I want every variable in the list to be a number in the range of 1 to 9. 
Currently I'm doing this like so:

```
between(1,9, A1),
between(1,9, A2),
% ...
between(1,9, C3).
```

Even though this works, it's already pretty ugly even for the only 9 numbers I have so far. However I will have to expand my list to contain at least 81 numbers at first (`A1` till `I9`), and even 405 in the end.

I would rather not 'write' 405 lines of code just to limit the range of the numbers in the list, but since I'm new to Prolog, I don't know how I can improve this.

Comment: Before moving on, I would strongly advise you to actually try to learn the language. What you are asking here is _very_ basic and fundamental to using the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you will have to hardcode your list to include all the variables from A1 to I9. Then you can iterate through it:

```
foreach(X, Your_list) do between(1, 9, X).
```

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog you can simply do:

```
?- numlist(1,9,Puzzle).
Puzzle = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
```